# background color change with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I've seen it done, but can't really find how to do it... I'd like to have one background in an alert message on page load and then, after couple of seconds, slowly fade it into white. Just the background -- the message stays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to look at the [color](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) plugin or reference [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/) to do the color animations.

Quick example:

```
body{
    background-color:red;
}

$("body").animate({
    backgroundColor : "white"
}, 5000);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/7SmX8/)

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this without jQuery UI?

Comment: Can I get some min UI without bells and whistles that it comes with? Seems like even if I just select CORE it packs tons of files.

Comment: Try selecting just the "Effects Core" on the download.  The description says "Extends the internal jQuery effects, includes morphing, easing and is required by all other effects."

Comment: I think their download selector in not working properly. Even if I select just Effects Core is packs tons of files, anything and everything.

Comment: IMHO there is no need to add extra stuffs.

Answer (score 2):

> - **DEMO:** http://so.devilmaycode.it/background-color-change-with-jquery

i could immagine something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.modal').fadeIn(500,function() {
        $(this).animate({
            'background-color': "#FFF"
        },
        1000,function() {
            $(this).fadeOut(500)
        });
    });
});

#fade{display:none;position:absolute;top:0%;left:0%;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:black;z-index:1001;-moz-opacity:0.8;opacity:.80;filter:alpha(opacity=80);}

#light{display:none;position:absolute;top:35%;left:35%;width:300px;height:50px;padding:16px;background-color:white;z-index:1002;overflow:auto;color:#333}

<div id="light" class="modal">Loading...</div>
<div id="fade" class="modal"></div>
```